# Concatenating columns to a dataframe after unpackingbits

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation, multiple-columns

I have a dataframe with 3 columns and the following values

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
df.loc[0] = [4, 6, 8]
df.loc[1] = [5, 9, 7]
df.loc[2] = [8, 2, 1]
```

The resulting dataframe will look like this:

```
    a  b  c

0   4  6  8
1   5  9  7
2   8  2  1
```

I want to convert the first two numbers (or columns) in each row to their corresponding 8-bit binary values and replace them in the df. But retain the last columns df['c'] as is.

For example, df.loc[0] should be converted to

```
    df.loc[0] = [0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,8]
```

Here, in df.loc[0] the first eight 0s and 1s are equivalent to 4, the next eight are equivalent to 6. But the last number remains in int.

Here is what I am doing:

```
    # save df.iloc[0, 'c'] in a different dataframe
    df_1.iloc[0, 'c'] = df.iloc[0, 'c']
    df.drop(columns='c', inplace=True)
    each_row = np.array(df.iloc[0, 'a']) # read each row
    each_row = np.array(each_row, dtype=np.uint8) #convert them to uint8 type
    each_row = np.unpackbits(each_row)
    each_row = pd.Series(each_row.astype(int)) #convert uint8 back to a series to concatenate to a dataframe
```

Now I want to insert columns a, b and then copy back c.

How do I replace the 4 and 6 in df.loc[0] with the values from the variable each_row? Is there an efficient way to do this for all rows of the dataframe without running them in a for loop?

Comment: May I know the final look of col `c` ?

Comment: There is some confusion in your question. your example of converting a row, you're mentionning `df['a']`. But `df['a']` is a column, not a row. A row would be [a=4,b= 5,c= 8]
You actually want to convert a and b, but not c, unline what your example shows. NB each column is a "Series" of a single type. You can't really have mixed type within a column.

Comment: My apologies. I want to convert two columns df['a'] and df['b'] into their 8-bit binary equivalents. But retain df['c'] as int.

Comment: @Wli, I have edited my question. Hope it clarifies.

Comment: The question is still invalid. Rows are 0,1,2, not a,b,c. So it seems that when you write `df['a'] = [0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,8]` you really mean `df.loc[0] = [0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,8]` (which wouldn't work anyway as you would change the length or the array from 3 to 17). Can you give an explicit complete dataframe of the desired output? Have you checked my answer and is any of the proposed possibilities what you want?

Comment: Thanks mozway. I made another attempt to clear up the confusion in my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can try some confusing-looking dictionary comprehension.

```
d = {col: np.append(np.concatenate(df.loc[:1, col].apply(lambda x: list(f'{x:08b}'))), df.loc[2, col]) for col in df.columns}
new_df = pd.DataFrame(d)

    a  b  c
0   0  0  0
1   0  0  0
2   0  0  0
3   0  0  0
4   0  0  1
5   1  1  0
6   0  0  0
7   0  1  0
8   0  0  0
9   0  0  0
10  0  0  0
11  0  0  0
12  0  1  0
13  1  0  0
14  1  0  1
15  0  1  0
16  8  7  1
```

Answer (score 1):

While your question is a bit confusing, from the value you provide, I imagine that you indeed want to map [4, 6, 8] to [0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,8].
You should edit you question for a more detailed answer.

Below is a step by step construction of different functions to reach this goal.

### Outputs a Series of binary representations:

```
def my_format(s):
    return format(s['a'], '08b')+format(s['b'], '08b')+str(s['c'])
df.apply(my_format, axis=1)
```

output:

```
0    00000100000001018
1    00000110000010012
2    00001000000001111
```

### Outputs a Series of lists:

```
def my_format2(s):
    return list(map(int, ''.join(map('{:08b}'.format, s[:2]))))+[s[2]]
df.apply(my_format2, axis=1)
```

output:

```
0    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, ...
1    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, ...
2    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, ...
```

### Outputs a DataFrame

```
def my_format3(s):
    return pd.Series(list(map(int, ''.join(map('{:08b}'.format, s[:2]))))+[s[2]])
df.apply(my_format3, axis=1)
```

output:

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16
0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   8
1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   8
2   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   8
```

### edit: another possibility

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[4,6,8],[4,9,7],[8,2,1]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
df[['a', 'b']] = df[['a', 'b']].applymap('{:08b}'.format)
df
```

output: (NB. a and b are strings if you want to keep the leading zeros)

```
          a         b  c
0  00000100  00000110  8
1  00000100  00001001  7
2  00001000  00000010  1
```

Comment: Thanks mozway. I have edited the question with clarifications.

Comment: @python_beginner I realize this question was never solved, had you managed to do what you wanted to? I added another option if need be ;)

Comment: Looks like I'm victim of the [no-edit-possible bug](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425430/how-can-i-avoid-an-error-occurred-submitting-the-edit-error-message-working), so here it is as comment `s = df.stack()
; out = pd.Series(list(np.unpackbits(s.to_numpy(dtype='uint8')[:,None], axis=1)), index=s.index).unstack()`